# How does type unification/function application work at a high level in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I feel like I'm not really getting how function application works or maybe I'm fixating on something that I shouldn't be.

Let's try to determine the type signature of `(fmap .)`

`fmap :: (x -> y) -> f x -> f y`

`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c -- signatures taken from GHC`

Applying `fmap` to `(.)`, we esentially wanna make `(x -> y) -> f x -> f y` and `(b -> c)` equal. When I first tried to do this I remember having a really hard time. You gotta match a set of 4 variables to a set of 2, so obviously you gotta do some grouping, but how? There's 3 possible solutions that I see, are all of them valid? Or is it only 1? I read that parentheses aren't really taken into consideration by the compiler, so we end up with `x -> y -> f x -> f y` and `b -> c`, but also functions associate to the right, so `fmap` should actually look like `x -> (y -> (f x -> f y))`, which lead me to

`b = x`

`c = y -> f x -> f y`

resulting in `(a -> x) -> (a -> y -> f x -> f y)` as a signature for `(fmap .)`.

The grouping I've seen this solved with though is `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`. So

`b = x -> y`

`c = f x -> f y`

leading to `(a -> x -> y) -> a -> f x -> f y`, which is more or less the same as GHC's `(a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> f a2 -> f b` if you rename some type variables.

Now to compare the 2 results, parentheses removed:

`a -> x -> a -> y -> f x -> f y`

`a -> x -> y -> a -> f x -> f y`

We can clearly see that the 3rd and 4th parameter types are switched, which means they're obviously not the same since `flip` is a thing. Which means this substitution

`b = x`

`c = y -> f x -> f y`

is not valid. Or am I missing something?

I have a feeling that I'm trying to make the functions work based on the signatures when I should be doing it the other way around. `:t fmap 'c'` fails with `Couldn't match expected type 'a -> b' with actual type 'Char'` which means that you can't really
partially apply the `a -> b` part of `fmap`. You can only partially apply `fmap`itself and its first argument is indivisible I guess. I don't know if I'm getting the pattern behind it all though.

I should really try to write a typed lambda calculus.

Comment: note, you are talking about `fmap (.)`. `(fmap .)` means something rather different, a section of the `.` operator, equivalent to `\f -> fmap . f`

Comment: `(fmap .)` is `(.) fmap`, not `fmap (.)`.

Comment: Yes, a function is indivisible. It's not comprised of an argument value and a return value; it's a value of its own that *produces* a return value when given an argument.

Comment: Ignoring partial application in that sense, what function of type `Char -> Char` do you think `fmap 'c' 'd'` would map over a list like `['x', 'y', 'z']`?

Comment: Think of it like this: The subtraction operator `-` is not associative. That means, in general, `x - (y - z)` isn't equal to `(x - y) - z`. So, when we write something like `x - y - z`, we have to agree on how the parentheses get put in. We *can* write that, but we have to agree on the rule for the parens. This is also how it is with the `->` operator. It turns out that putting the parens "to the right" for `->` allows you to use fewer parens for the more common case. This is ultimately just for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

> There's 3 possible solutions that I see, are all of them valid?

No.

> Or is it only 1?

Only one. `(x -> y) -> f x -> f y` is equal to `(x -> y) -> (f x -> f y)` and only to that since `->` is right associative. Putting parentheses in other points is wrong.

> I read that parentheses aren't really taken into consideration by the compiler,

That's false. The compiler implicitly works as parentheses are always added in a right-associative way: the type `a -> b -> c -> d` is handled as `a -> (b -> (c -> d))`, only. By contrast, the type `(a -> b) -> c -> d` is handled as `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)`, only, and the type `(a -> b -> c) -> d` is handled as `(a -> (b -> c)) -> d`, only.

> so we end up with `x -> y -> f x -> f y` and `b -> c`,

No, that's wrong, you must keep the parentheses.
We must satisfy the type equality

```
(x -> y) -> (f x -> f y)
~
b -> c
```

and the unique solution to this is

```
b ~ (x -> y)
c ~ (f x -> f y)
```

as you found out later.

To understand what's going on in unification, I think it's beneficial if you start by adding the implicit parentheses in a right-associative way. If you do that, you can forget about types like `a -> b -> c`, and only care about the fundamental case `(T -> U)` and its unification step:

```
from (T1 -> U1) ~ (T2 -> U2)
deduce T1 ~ T2 and U1 ~ U2
```

Comment: The nice property of interest here is not uniqueness, but generality. There are other solutions (e.g. `(Int -> Int) -> (f Int -> f Int)`), but they are all available as specializations of the solution you gave.